# After Effects JSX subtitle export script - Cyrillic issue

Tags: javascript, jsx, after-effects

I have an After Effects file containing subtitles in multiple languages.  I’m using the attached script to export the subtitles in each language to a plain text file.  This works fine for latin languages - but doesn’t work for non-latin languages (Cyrillic ie russian, slavic etc) where I simply get a time stamp and blank return..  I have tried changing my macs language and keyboard settings - but no luck - can anyone offer any pointers or anything to try that can point me in the correct direction please?

```js
/*
 Subtitle Exporter v01   
 Script by Philipp Grolle
 www.display-artists.de
 
 
 Instructions:
 Select all the Text Layers you want to export, run the script, and save the file as .srt
 
 Attention: The Script has not been debugged or testet. Try it on your own risk!


*/

// get all the selected Layers 
var theComp = app.project.activeItem;
var alleLayer = theComp.selectedLayers;

// count how many layers are selected
var anzahlLayer = alleLayer.length;


// Enable the line below if you want to change the order of your text (ascending / descending)
/* alleLayer.reverse(); */


   // prompt to save file
   var theFile = File.saveDialog("Save the text file.", "untitled.txt", "TEXT txt");
   
   // if user didn't cancel...
   if (theFile != null) {
      
      // open file for "w"riting,
      theFile.open("w","TEXT","????");
      
         // Do it for all the selected Layers
         for (x = 0; x < anzahlLayer; x++)
         
         {
                    
             // get In- and Outpoint of the current Layer and convert to timecode (00:00:00:00)
            var timecodeIn = timeToCurrentFormat(alleLayer[x].inPoint, 25);
            var timecodeOut = timeToCurrentFormat(alleLayer[x].outPoint, 25);
            
            
           // split the value of the inPoint; converting last 2 characters  (frames) to milliseconds, and finally join it again with comma instead of colon
            var str_in= timecodeIn;
            var timeCodeAnfang_in=str_in.slice(0,8); 
            var timeCodeEnde_in=str_in.slice(9,11); 
            var millisek_in = timeCodeEnde_in*40; // 1000 milliseconds divided by 25 fps = 40
            var zusammen_in = timeCodeAnfang_in +"," + millisek_in;
            
            
            //split the value of the outPoint; converting last 2 characters  (frames) to milliseconds, and finally join it again with comma instead of colon
            var str_out= timecodeOut;
            var timeCodeAnfang_out=str_out.slice(0,8); 
            var timeCodeEnde_out=str_out.slice(9,11); 
            var millisek_out = timeCodeEnde_out*40;
            var zusammen_out = timeCodeAnfang_out +"," + millisek_out;
            
            //counter for the number above the timecode (in the results)
            var zaehler = x+1;
            
            //writing the results to file
            theFile.write(zaehler);
            theFile.write("\r\n");
            theFile.write(zusammen_in);
            theFile.write(" --> "); 
            theFile.write(zusammen_out);
            theFile.write("\r\n");
            theFile.write(alleLayer[x].property("Source Text").value);           
            theFile.write("\r\n\n");
         }

   
      // close the text file
      theFile.close();
      
      // open text file in default app
      theFile.execute();
   }
```

Comment: Seems After Effects doesn't play nice with text encoding. Maybe what's [here](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1025489) can help?